# Cassandra: Intermittent connection error: NoHostAvailableException

Tags: java, cassandra

I intermittently get the following error when I try to execute a query on Cassandra cluster:

```
 com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)

    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:108)

    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.execute(SessionManager.java:525)

    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeQuery(SessionManager.java:561)

    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:118)
```

The cluster is very much alive with all nodes up. Cassandra logs are not showing any error or connection issue when this exception occurs.

App Details:

- JDK 1.7
- Cassandra v2.1.2 [4 nodes]
- Cassandra Java Driver v2.1.4
- [cassandra.yaml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/892221/cassandra.yaml)

How do I resolve this issue? or where can I look for logs related to this issue?

Comment: What is your network topology? I can see that your listen address is set to 192.168.34.163, but rpc_address is 192.168.34.16. Where the client is trying to connect from (ip)? Can you access ports from the client location (using telnet for example)?

Comment: The ip is 192.168.34.163 only. It was a typo. The actual configuration has rpc_address as 192.168.34.163

Comment: What about the rest of my question?

Comment: We are operating on a 4 node cluster in same data-center.

Comment: Where the client is trying to connect from (ip)? Can you access ports from the client location (using telnet for example)?